# php - WordPress - serving images if customer is logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I have a magazine to serve online to those who bought it. I need some kind of `serve-image.php?img=page1.jpg` to use in `<img src="...">`, which would pull the images from a directory not accessible to the public. This part is solved. What isn't figured out is how do I check from this `serve-image.php` file if the user is logged into WordPress (and bought the thing.) Do I have to create some simple API for that? Is there something I am not thinking of?

Thank you for any answers!

Comment: What system do you use for your shop? To check wheter a visitor is logged in or not you can call `is_user_logged_in()` which returns `true` if the user is logged in. Do you already have access to the Wordpress functionalities in the scope of your `serve-image.php`?

Comment: I use WooCommerce. I am looking for a way to pass the image data into `<img src="serve-image.php?img=file.jpg">` essentially, as far as I can see, the only way is to create `serve-image.php` script, from which I have to somehow check if the user is logged in and bought the thing. And I have no access to WP from the external file. Maybe use some page and in there a shortcode, so it's not out of scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following method:

Create a `.htaccess` file in your protected image folder which redirects all calls to the index with the requested image path (you might use relative paths) as an argument `serve_image`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?serve_image=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
Options All -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
```

Then, in your plugin or functions.php include the access check by hooking it to the `parse_request` action (this is the code you would have used in your `serve-image.php`-file):

```
add_action('parse_request', 'check_file_access');

// function to check access and serve image
function check_file_access() {

    if(!isset($_GET['serve_image')){
        return false;
    }

    // Check access
    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        die('Sorry! No access!');
    }

    // sanitize here (only allow paths that are inside your specified folder)
    $image_path = $_GET["serve_image"];

    // get content type
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $content_type = finfo_file($finfo, $image_path);
    finfo_close($finfo);

    // construct file name
    $filename = basename($image_path,'.'.$finfo['extension']);

    header('Content-type: '.$content_type);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);

    readfile($image_path);

    exit();
}
```

Now if you want to display one of the protected images, you can simply use the regular path to the image in the `src` attribute. The image source will be denied to users which have no access.

Comment: I think it is now appropriate to use some profane word to explain, how good is your answer! Thank you! I was thinking in the wrong direction all this time! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I was trying to do a smiliar thing recently and found this to be the simplest solution to decouple the access control from the url.